# firebird sql month time cumulated

Tags: sql, timestamp, firebird

I am trying to get the following out my firebird db:
I have records with a Timestamp attribute and an attribute with a currency value. Now I want query the currency value cumulated by month and now comes the tricky thing for me: I want each month starting from the first day at 16:30:00 p.m til the next first day in the next month at 16:29:59. I am not sure how to add this in the where condition or somewhere else? Thx for helping me!

eg.
Timestamp                Value
...
2012-07-31 17:05:03      23,--
2012-08-01 12:23:15      15,--
cut:
2012-08-01 16:35:56      25,--
2012-08-02 12:23:15      5,--
2012-08-25 18:03:34      6,--
2012-08-31 08:03:55      9,--
2012-09-01 12:23:15      7,--
cut:
2012-09-01 16:47:43      3,--
2012-09-02 19:13:10      8,--
2012-09-10 19:13:10      18,--
2012-09-30 19:13:10      3,--
2012-10-02 19:13:10      8,--
....

July: 23,-- + 15,-- = 38,-
August: 52,--
September: 32,--
Oktober: 8,--   and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to shift the date back (or forward) so that the start time of this month falls on 00:00 of the first of the month, and then simply group by the year and month part of the timestamp:

With a simple table I get the expected results using:

```
WITH shifteddate AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, DATEADD(HOUR, -16, infodate)) shifteddate, infovalue
    FROM SUMEXAMPLE
)
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM shifteddate), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM shifteddate), SUM(infovalue)
FROM shifteddate
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

You could also use subquery instead of a CTE, but I just find this easier to read.